# CSS Help with Anchor Tag

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head> 
<style type="text/css">
 a{
    color: #753C52;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border: solid 1px yellow;
  }

.viewInBrowserLinkStyle {
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 14px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    text-decoration:underlined;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" class="viewInBrowserLinkStyle ">
This is a link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I am able to override every property other than "text-decoration"! Why is it so ? How can i override the text-decoration that is defined in anchor tag with the one that is defined in the class?

Please advice!

Comment: Fastest gun in the west!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `underline`, not `underlined`.

Answer (score 4):

*underlined* should be *underline*

Answer (score 0):

Because it is `text-decoration: underline`

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to change your stylesheet a little. So instead of `.viewInBrowserLinkStyle` you should use `a.viewInBrowserLinkStyle`. Then it will work. This is because you are globally specifying all anchor tags to not be underlined. And to override that you need to specify any anchor tag with that classname needs to have an underline.

Comment: Huh? A class selector by itself is more specific than a type (element) selector. There's nothing wrong with the selectors he's using now.

Comment: @BoltClock, Yeah you are right. Sorry it's way too early in the morning for me. Maybe I should stop answering questions before I have had a coffee. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong the attribute, it's `text-decoration: underline`, not *underlined*.
If still you don't uses, I recommend to you use debug tools, it's more easy to identify these problems and erros.

This link shows some CSS debug tools: http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/html-and-css-debugging-tools